# Beginners switch case action is always default

Tags: c

i have just entered a switch case code.. i don't understand why when i am pressing '1', it is still going to the default case always.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char c = 0;
    int x = 0, y = 0;

    printf("Please write 2 numbers:\n");
    scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
    printf("Please choose an action from the math menu:\n\n1.add\n2.sub\n");
    scanf(" %c", &c);

    switch (c)
    {
    case 1:
        printf("%d + %d is %d\n", x, y, x+y);
        break;

    default: printf("Wrong value\n");
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try ``case 49``.  ``case 1`` is actually triggered by the SOH character.  See [this](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: or simply `case '1'`

Comment: or if you prefer use a `int` and number (`int c = 0;` and `scanf(" %d", &c);`). Just be coherent beetween values you read and values you test.

Answer (score 3):

As `c` is declared as having character type then entered 1 and 2 are characters correspondingly '1' and '2'.

So write

```
switch (c)
{
case '1':
    printf("%d + %d is %d\n", x, y, x+y);
    break;

case '2':
    printf("%d - %d is %d\n", x, y, x-y);
    break;

default: printf("Wrong value\n");
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The character 0 to 9 are actually ascii values 48 to 57. switch( (int)(c-48) )  would work.  The express (int)(c-48) changes the ascii digits to integers.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the previous answer using character literals:

```
switch(c)
{
  case '1':
    ...
    break;
  ...
 }
```

This allows you to even handle 'q' and the like.

When doing 'q', keep in mind the case sensitivity:

```
switch(c)
{
  case 'q':
  case 'Q':
    ... handle q
    break;
}
```

In short: You are reading a char, treat it as a char.